# perl oneliner - random string generator with non-alphanumeric

Tags: perl

how to add non-alphanumeric characters to the map so it generates mix of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters?

```
$ for i in {1..5};do perl -le 'print map { (a..z,A..Z,0..9)[rand 62] } 0..pop' 100;done
feUhC59cHXl1s39T1LIiQVQVhVOMI9I2c11wZZKjitE4gVl4LAup7s2ZUeprkSWBqNkEiZVM66m73Zkk2lRb37VcgEz5PDX0YIMao
mjIvFkxFLyzw6BXwnqLj3SrliLXivrvDFhB6Vo9R8pnemm8LlyzeXeNF9x5haCvS8iLHRflPn1wpORlexka1G2yi9E8tDRXi0sNYt
FT2SpObqjVaHhSw18zegl4V2C6SOWe65HEJwA4U2EpOBpWukTThdzgaRCLAjOfHmAocZpPhdnyIe3SmvGncODw1W6gR9j8GjLWUbq
jCmX3J34hOcDiOkpSTadMyChkO8jkGOiThbE9W2esnHRPGutBCPVTxLIuLN7onlYnMKrD7oGzPG0szpS6ijoncXSzn3MzdwrFLWJw
H4vmVPWcOqwieRagETfUJJA7wIrIFOB6LcANFSnC5fJeZ9KJvusfABFa50NWQ8NugeIpP4nrIWzNLkZhLiCuCLlNbkAPpBgCvB9Ga
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [chr](http://p3rl.org/chr) function:

```
perl -le 'print map chr 33 + rand 94, 1 .. 1000'
```

Comment: thank you, it works great, could you please tell me how to create own map of non-alhpanumeric chars? eg. if I would like to have only ! and - on the random strings?

Answer (score 1):

Since in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428584/perl-oneliner-random-string-generator-with-non-alphanumeric#comment773586_428588) you asked for a way to add custom characters, one way to do that is to just add them to the list with `qw//`, just remember to update the count in `rand 67`.

```
perl -le 'print map { (a..z,A..Z,0..9,qw{- _ / & ?})[rand 67] } 0..100'
```

Comment: If you set `@a=(a..z,...)` you can then use `rand @a` instead of the fixed `rand 67`

Comment: nice, thank you. is there a way to get at least 1 of specified special charactes in each string/output?

Comment: @DonJ It'd be better if you state all of your requirements from the beginning. Sounds like you're generating passwords, have you researched that?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that this is more than just some one-liner challenge you're dealing with, and want to learn more, there are ways of making this a little easier to develop and maintain.  (wait, did I just use those words about a Perl one-liner?!)

I hate having to count characters and update when I change things.
Unless you're committed to it just being a *single* line of Perl, I'd suggest building the list first and then using it, which means you can a) use some other way of constructing the list of characters, and b) ask it how long it is later.

I like the useful character sets that Regular Expressions offer, to let you represent groups of related characters (if that's meaningful for your use case), so a somewhat more generalized approach that I would take is:

Build the list of characters (using your example, and adding "!" and "-" as mentioned in your comment).  What this does is generate *all* 7-bit ASCII characters (up to 127), then keeps only what matches the character class:

```
@chars = grep /[a-zA-Z0-9!-]/, map chr, 0..127
```

Then emit a random sequence of them ("rand @chars" forces "@chars" into numeric context, and gives you the 0-based length of the array):

```
print map { $chars[rand @chars] } 0..pop
```

Put it together and it looks like this:

```
perl -le '@chars = grep /[a-zA-Z0-9!-]/, map chr, 0..127;print map { $chars[rand @chars] } 0..pop' 100
```

You could simply add each character explicitly to the class (be careful to escape things that need it:  e.g. I only *didn't* escape the dash because it's at the end)

Read some or all of the [perlrecharclass documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) for additional information.

In my example, I only went up to "127" because it looked like you were only interested in basic 7-bit ASCII stuff.

If you're interested in some more esoteric stuff, you'll have to run up to larger numbers.
For some numeric-ish fun, try:

```
@chars = grep /\p{Numeric_Type=Digit}/, map chr, 0..65535
```

Comment: This is a nice little tutorial, but the question says “add non-alphanumeric characters to the map so it generates mix of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters”, and you have added only **`-`** (hyphen).   There are 32 other printable non-alphanumeric (ASCII) characters; what about them?

Comment: Good point.  I was going based off the comment left on a different answer, which asked for "!" and "-" by way of example.  The question is getting murkier anyway, so I'll wait and see if it's turned into something clearer.  Will edit to make it clearer that I'm addressing the comment.